# Android Toast in iPhone?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios

When I write Android apps, I love the Toast feature. Is there a way to get this kind of set and forget popup message in iPhone development using MonoTouch (C# .NET)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this out:

https://github.com/ecstasy2/toast-notifications-ios

Edit: The project has moved to github so i update the link.

Comment: Can i test it on siumulator? Doesnt seem to work for me. I have created a toast in the viewDidLoad method of my controller.

Comment: This is really nice, but is LGPL-licensed so you can't use it in an iPhone app without making all your source be under the LGPL too. The reason it's different on the iPhone to usual is the iPhone uses static libraries ..

Comment: Just changed the licence to MIT. The goal is to allow everyone to use it without restriction. So thank for the comment.

Answer (score 15):

MonoTouch Toast Version here. Inspired by Android.

To call it,

```
        ToastView t = new ToastView ("Email Sent", 1000);
        t.Show ();
```

Enum File:

```
public enum ToastGravity
{
    Top = 0,
    Bottom = 1,
    Center = 2
}
```

ToastSettings File:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
namespace General
{

    public class ToastSettings
    {
        public ToastSettings ()
        {
            this.Duration = 500;
            this.Gravity = ToastGravity.Center;
        }

        public int Duration
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public double DurationSeconds
        {
            get { return (double) Duration/1000 ;}

        }

        public ToastGravity Gravity
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public PointF Position
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


    }
}
```

Main Toast Class:

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;

namespace General
{
    public class ToastView : NSObject
    {

        ToastSettings theSettings = new ToastSettings ();

        private string text = null;
        UIView view;
        public ToastView (string Text, int durationMilliseonds)
        {
            text = Text;
            theSettings.Duration = durationMilliseonds;
        }

        int offsetLeft = 0;
        int offsetTop = 0;
        public ToastView SetGravity (ToastGravity gravity, int OffSetLeft, int OffSetTop)
        {
            theSettings.Gravity = gravity;
            offsetLeft = OffSetLeft;
            offsetTop = OffSetTop;
            return this;
        }

        public ToastView SetPosition (PointF Position)
        {
            theSettings.Position = Position;
            return this;
        }

        public void Show ()
        {
            UIButton v = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.Custom);
            view = v;

            UIFont font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize (16);
            SizeF textSize = view.StringSize (text, font, new SizeF (280, 60));

            UILabel label = new UILabel (new RectangleF (0, 0, textSize.Width + 5, textSize.Height + 5));
            label.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            label.TextColor = UIColor.White;
            label.Font = font;
            label.Text = text;
            label.Lines = 0;
            label.ShadowColor = UIColor.DarkGray;
            label.ShadowOffset = new SizeF (1, 1);


            v.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 0, textSize.Width + 10, textSize.Height + 10);
            label.Center = new PointF (v.Frame.Size.Width / 2, v.Frame.Height / 2);
            v.AddSubview (label);

            v.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA (0, 0, 0, 0.7f);
            v.Layer.CornerRadius = 5;

            UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0];

            PointF point = new PointF (window.Frame.Size.Width / 2, window.Frame.Size.Height / 2);

            if (theSettings.Gravity == ToastGravity.Top)
            {
                point = new PointF (window.Frame.Size.Width / 2, 45);
            }
            else if (theSettings.Gravity == ToastGravity.Bottom)
            {
                point = new PointF (window.Frame.Size.Width / 2, window.Frame.Size.Height - 45);
            }
            else if (theSettings.Gravity == ToastGravity.Center)
            {
                point = new PointF (window.Frame.Size.Width / 2, window.Frame.Size.Height / 2);
            }
            else
            {
                point = theSettings.Position;
            }

            point = new PointF (point.X + offsetLeft, point.Y + offsetTop);
            v.Center = point;
            window.AddSubview (v);
            v.AllTouchEvents += delegate { HideToast (null); };

            NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer (theSettings.DurationSeconds, HideToast);

        }


        void HideToast ()
        {
            UIView.BeginAnimations ("");
            view.Alpha = 0;
            UIView.CommitAnimations ();
        }

        void RemoveToast ()
        {
            view.RemoveFromSuperview ();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Good job guy, your translation is perfect.

Comment: This is a C# class so in AnyThingYouWant.cs is fine

Comment: what do I need to change for landscape view?

Answer (score 4):

Here's my version: http://github.com/scalessec/toast

I think it's simpler to use because it's implemented as a obj-c category, thereby adding the makeToast methods to any instance of UIView. eg:

```
[self.view makeToast:@"This is some message as toast."
            duration:3.0
            position:@"bottom"];
```

Comment: Is there a way to disable the parent view so the user cannot click away from the activity toast? I need the user to stop interacting with the app while the activity toast is showing. (Only the activity toast, the rest don't need this behaviour.)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like `UIAlertView`?

Comment: No, that requires a timer to show and hide. Something simpler, perhaps a canned class from the Open Source community. Toasts internally take care of more of the plumbing.

Comment: Why not create a class that wraps up the alert view and timer? Maybe you could then open source that, thus solving your problem and maybe other people's problems.

Comment: Jasarien is right, the problem you want to solve is quite simple and is also really useful, toasts rock. It would be great help to the community.

Comment: The answer I accepted is perfect for this. I will translate it into MonoTouch so all the Microsoft.NET iOS developers can use it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think it is something usefull so share it. Actualy not much developer have downloaded it yet and i'll publish some update very soon including custom alert themes+icons.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this link for objective-c code for Toast

http://code.google.com/p/toast-notifications-ios/source/browse/trunk/

While this link for its usage

http://code.google.com/p/toast-notifications-ios/wiki/HowToUse

which could be like any one of the below samples

```
[[iToast makeText:NSLocalizedString(@"The activity has been successfully saved.", @"")] show];

[[[iToast makeText:NSLocalizedString(@"The activity has been successfully saved.", @"")] 
                          setGravity:iToastGravityBottom] show];

[[[[iToast makeText:NSLocalizedString(@"Something to display a very long time", @"")] 
                  etGravity:iToastGravityBottom] setDuration:iToastDurationLong] show];
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be after Local Notifications, pretty sure they allow you to set a time, I think in epoch time to be fired off. Don't think there is a way to hide them though. I might be misunderstanding your question though cause I'm unfamiliar with Toast.

Answer (score 1):

Just You can use the following code with uilabel and uianimation to get toast like in android.
It does two works one is toast task and it increases the height of the label according to the text length with wordwrap IOS 7 later [link here](http://johniphone.blogspot.in/2014/03/toast-in-ios7-as-in-android.html)

```
CGRect initialFrame = CGRectMake(20, self.view.frame.size.height/2,300, 40);


NSString *message=@"Toast in Iphone as in Android";
UILabel *flashLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:initialFrame];
flashLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Optima-Italic" size:12.0];
flashLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
flashLabel.layer.cornerRadius=3.0f;
flashLabel.numberOfLines=0;
flashLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(flashLabel.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);

CGRect labelRect = [message boundingRectWithSize:maxSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:flashLabel.font} context:nil];

//adjust the label the the new height.
CGRect newFrame = flashLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = labelRect.size.height;
flashLabel.frame = newFrame;
flashLabel.text=message;
[self.view addSubview:flashLabel];

flashLabel.alpha=1.0;
self.view.userInteractionEnabled=FALSE;

[UIView animateWithDuration:13.0 animations:^
{
    flashLabel.alpha=0.0f;
}
completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;

    [flashLabel removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified John's answer as follows:

Toast.h

```
@interface Toast : NSObject

+ (void)toast:(NSString *)message
             :(UIView *) view
             :(int)delay;

@end
```

Toast.m

```
#import "Toast.h"

@interface Toast ()

@end

@implementation Toast

+ (void)toast:(NSString *)message
             :(UIView *) view
             :(int)delay
{
    CGRect initialFrame = CGRectMake(10, view.frame.size.height/2, 300, 40);
    UILabel *flashLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:initialFrame];
    flashLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Optima-Italic" size:19.0];
    flashLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    flashLabel.layer.cornerRadius=9.0f;
    flashLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
    flashLabel.numberOfLines=3;
    flashLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(flashLabel.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);
    CGRect labelRect = [message boundingRectWithSize:maxSize
                                             options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                          attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:flashLabel.font}
                                             context:nil];

    //adjust the label the the new height.
    CGRect newFrame = flashLabel.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = labelRect.size.height * 2;
    flashLabel.frame = newFrame;
    flashLabel.text=message;
    [view addSubview:flashLabel];
    flashLabel.alpha=1.0;
    view.userInteractionEnabled=FALSE;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:delay animations:^
    {
        flashLabel.alpha=0.0f;
    }

    completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        view.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;
        [flashLabel removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a little modification to the toast class that handles rotation of the display.

```
        public void Show ()
    {
        UIButton v = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.Custom);
        view = v;


        UIFont font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize (16);
        SizeF textSize = view.StringSize (text, font, new SizeF (280, 60));

        UILabel label = new UILabel (new RectangleF (0, 0, textSize.Width + 5, textSize.Height + 5));
        label.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        label.TextColor = UIColor.White;
        label.Font = font;
        label.Text = text;
        label.Lines = 0;
        label.ShadowColor = UIColor.DarkGray;
        label.ShadowOffset = new SizeF (1, 1);


        v.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 0, textSize.Width + 10, textSize.Height + 10);
        label.Center = new PointF (v.Frame.Size.Width / 2, v.Frame.Height / 2);
        v.AddSubview (label);

        v.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA (0, 0, 0, 0.7f);
        v.Layer.CornerRadius = 5;

        UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0];

        PointF point = new PointF (window.Frame.Size.Width / 2, window.Frame.Size.Height / 2);

        if (theSettings.Gravity == ToastGravity.Top)
        {
            point = new PointF (window.Frame.Size.Width / 2, 45);
        }
        else if (theSettings.Gravity == ToastGravity.Bottom)
        {
            point = new PointF (window.Frame.Size.Width / 2, window.Frame.Size.Height - 45);
        }
        else if (theSettings.Gravity == ToastGravity.Center)
        {
            point = new PointF (window.Frame.Size.Width / 2, window.Frame.Size.Height / 2);
        }
        else
        {
            point = theSettings.Position;
        }

        point = new PointF (point.X + offsetLeft, point.Y + offsetTop);
        v.Center = point;
        //handle screen rotation
        float orientation=0;

        switch(UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarOrientation)
        {
        case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
            orientation=-90;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
            orientation=90;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
            orientation=180;
            break;
        }
        v.Transform=CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation ((float)(orientation / 180f * Math.Pi));
        window.AddSubview (v);
        v.AllTouchEvents += delegate { HideToast (); };

        NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer (theSettings.DurationSeconds, HideToast);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try my open source library TSMessages: https://github.com/toursprung/TSMessages

It's really easy to use and looks beautiful on iOS 5/6 and on iOS 7 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I really like MonoTouch solution proposed by Bahai.

The following is not a substitution. Is just a ready-to-go one method the worked for me.

```
    private async Task ShowToast(string message, UIAlertView toast = null)
    {
        if (null == toast)
        {
            toast = new UIAlertView(null, message, null, null, null);
            toast.Show();
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            await ShowToast(message, toast);
            return;
        }

        UIView.BeginAnimations("");
        toast.Alpha = 0;
        UIView.CommitAnimations();
        toast.DismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, true);
    }
```

If the method is called from a background thread (not the main UI thread) then BeginInvokeOnMainThread is required which means just call it like this.

```
BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
 ShowToast(message);
});
```

Comment: This blocks user interaction till the time Toast is displayed, this is not the case with Toast in Android.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. How would you avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is for Xamarin platform, here are few lines of code that work. _toast is a private class member ShowAlertInToast is a public member.

```
public void ShowAlertInToast (string text)
{
                    _toast = new UIAlertView ("", text, (IUIAlertViewDelegate)null, null, null);
                    _toast.Show ();
        
                    //1.5 seconds
                    NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer (new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,1500), (obj) => { HideAlertInToast (); });
        
    }
        
     private void HideAlertInToast()
     {
                    if (_toast != null) {
                        _toast.DismissWithClickedButtonIndex (0, true);
                    }
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

I created a new repo on github with a class to do iOS toast-style alerts. I didn't like the one on code.google.com, it didn't rotate properly and wasn't pretty.

https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-toast

Enjoy folks.

Comment: Making it dependent on the huge Three20 library makes it too heavyweight IMO

Comment: I've been using it successfully for over a year, but of course each project should include what your heart tells you.