# Instagram "like" animation iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I want to implement the "like" animation that Instagram uses when you double tap a picture into my iOS app. It is a pretty slick feature and think it would add a little flavor to my app. I posted the before and after photos of the double tap. The heart fades in and out in about two seconds. I can not figure it out. Let me know!

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: So you want to fade in a view with a HUD and a white shape in the middle? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this using framesequance if you want to go with animation aproach.

Toast (as it is in android) aproach is also perfect and for that you can check a duplicate question [Growl/toast style notifications library for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026273/growl-toast-style-notifications-library-for-ios) here.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define LIKED 100 //change as per your requirement
#define UNLIKE 200 //change as per your requirement

- (void) likeUnlike:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [imageViewSub setHidden:NO];

    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)sender.view;

    if(imageView.tag==LIKED)
    {
        [imageViewSub setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unlike.png"]];
        [imageView setTag:UNLIKE];
    }
    else
    {
        [imageViewSub setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like.png"]];
        [imageView setTag:LIKED];
    }

    //here, your like/unlike update call to server for store selection.

    //set the frame exactly you want or
    //implement some other way to hide `imageViewSub` after like/unlike
    [imageViewSub setFrame:CGRectMake( 110, 180, 100, 100)];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"anim" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [imageViewSub setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 0, 0)]; 
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

//Add below code where you're added/showing your images. There's always two `UIImageView`s one is `main` and other one is `sub`.

[imageViewSub bringSubviewToFront:imageViewMain];

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[doubleTap addTarget:self action:@selector(likeUnlike:)];
[imageViewMain addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
[doubleTap release];
```

P.S. `imageViewMain` will initially having tag from `UNLIKED` and `imageViewSub` having `unlike.png` and should be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

In some of my projects I've been using [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD). You can set the standard images/progress circle, or custom images, and customize the font of the label also. I pretty like it. If you use it together with performBlockAfterDelay [(check this category)](https://gist.github.com/1896002), it can save you a lot of time and make you life easier.